# Why does my application still run after closing main window?

Tags: java, swing

If I make a JFrame like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     new JFrame().setVisible(true);
}
```

then after closing the window the appication doesn't stop (I need to kill it).

What is the proper way of showing application's main windows ?

I'd also like to know a reason of a proposed solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should call the `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` in your JFrame.

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable guiCreator = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame fenster = new JFrame("Hallo Welt mit Swing");
            fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            fenster.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(guiCreator);
}
```

Comment: I hate Java sometimes.  That should be the default behaviour, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok i found the reason - there are two additional AWT threads running and that's why my application doesn't end when the "main" method ends. I always forget that JFrame is nonmodal and creates those threads.

Comment: Why should it be the default behavior?  Many applications create multiple windows.  If that were the default you'd have to change it whenever you create a new window.

Comment: totally agree that dispose_on_close should be the default.  For instance you need to also setDefaultcloseOperation for modal dialogs or they'll hang around and disallow your app from exiting. yikes.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between the application window and the application itself... The window runs in its own thread, and finishing `main()` will not end the application if other threads are still active. When closing the window you should also make sure to close the application, possibly by calling `System.exit(0);`

Yuval =8-)

Answer (score 3):

You must dispose the frame, invoking the dispose method in your window listener or using setDefaultCloseOperation. For the argument of the last one, you can use two options:

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` only dispose the frame resources.

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` disposes the frame resources and then invokes `System.exit`.

There is no real difference between the two unless you have non daemon threads.
I prefer to use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` because this way I'm able to notice if I forgot to terminate a thread, because the JVM will stop if there are no more threads running. That's also the reason closing a Frame without disposing will not terminate the application, since Swing creates a thread to handle events that is terminated only when dispose is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a *window listener* to the frame so the program terminates after you close it.

```java
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this (unless you're writing a very trivial single-window app, i.e. no other windows or threads etc..) is to catch the `windowClosing()` event, and then call the `dispose();` method of the form.

If your program doesn't completely exit after this, it means you have other non-deamon threads running, and you must stop these as best you see fit depending on your program.

Calling `System.exit()` or `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` will force stop any other threads (and the whole program), meaning your code is less portable, and force-stopping threads is obviously dangerous (in a programming kind of way).